# Where in Django does a user become an AnonymousUser?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying find out where/when exactly request.user becomes an AnonymousUser.  I've been searching through the entire Auth backend but I can't seem find it.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

I'm aware that every user that isn't an Authenticated user becomes an AnonymousUser, but I need to know where/when this happens for some code I'm building.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try adding an assert False to the constructor for AnonymouUser and see what the traceback says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`contrib\auth\__init__.py:80`

```
def get_user(request):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
    try:
        user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
        backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
        backend = load_backend(backend_path)
        user = backend.get_user(user_id) or AnonymousUser()
    except KeyError:
        user = AnonymousUser()
    return user
```

Comment: middleware will be executed before this - this is only a helper function, the magic is not happening here :)

Comment: I looked at your source. returns lazy objects. __This__ is where the magic actually happens.

Comment: well - this function will not be executed by itself you know. Question was: *where/when* exactly request.user becomes an AnonymousUser. So as for when - it is happening in the middleware. Don't see a point of giving down-vote mate :)

Comment: Whoops.. I've been staring at that page for at least 30 minutes.. and completely missed that because it's the last function in the page.

Comment: @bx2  it's sort of a combination of both answers above that I was looking for.  #1 where user = AnonymousUser() and then #2 what ultimately decides which user is set as.

Comment: Line 86: `user = backend.get_user(user_id) or AnonymousUser()`

Comment: @Chris cmon, we're dukeing it out for your approval here man. who wins?

Comment: it won't let me accept an answer until a certain amount of time after the question was asked @Thomas

Comment: @Thomas - yes this is `where` if the object was not called before :)

Answer (score 4):

it's all in `django.contrib.auth.middleware` module - look here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L49 for details.

Comment: your source calls my source L16: `request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))` and returns a lazy object which calls mine. mine actually sets the anonymous user. Lawyered.

Comment: i +1 'd this too, for what it's worth.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Thomas: hahah - both of them are not our objects so to speak - this is not a competition - I just wanted to help :) cheers!

Comment: Well played sir! *hat tip* 
Sorry if i play stackunderflow too competitively. It's like the ultimate gameshow, but with no prizes :(

Answer (score 0):

logout method in "contrib/auth/**init**.py" also affect AnonymousUser() to request.user, look at the code below:

```
if hasattr(request, 'user'):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
    request.user = AnonymousUser()
```